# Why does Google embed images, stylesheets, etc rather than using links

Tags: html, web

Doing a Google for 'BBC News' can be odd as often it shows the wrong image next to the headline, e.g. at the moment I've got a picture of Steve Bannon next to "Holiday maker dies ... caught in riptide"

The image isn't via a href, it's using src="data:image..."

The question is, why does Google put the styles, scripts and images directly on the page rather than using links, which would seem to be more efficient?

I'm not sure if it makes a difference but I'm behind a proxy in work at the moment

To make this more of a question, can someone supply links on the benefits for a website on embedding everything rather than using links

Comment: It's all about loading time and how HTTP1 works (check why they built SPDY or how HTTP2 works)

Comment: it's for loading time by data centralization.
 By putting everything in the page, clients will download everything only from google server. If the resources are linked from it's original server, there would be many loading time differences because a single google page result contain multiple website with different server capability.

Comment: Not sure on the last point. I'm assuming that all images, javascript, etc would be hosted on Google's servers which are all rapid, and the caching possibilities would be tremendous. The actual page size would then be an insignificant fraction of the original size. Just to be clear, I'm not arguing, this is Google, I'm sure they are right

Comment: If the image only exists once on the page, and it likely only exists on one page (because you're probably not going to visit the same search result page all that often), then there's no size advantage to put the image on an external URL, but there's a *tremendous* speed advantage in doing only one HTTP request instead of multiple.

Comment: I'm not going to, but I bet millions of other people will open google to get to bbc news and other sites, and I would have thought that would be the most common usecase here. The caching wouldn't be at the browser level but in the infrastructure above that

Comment: So what? *A* Google server has to serve the image anyway, yes. It doesn't make a difference *to Google* whether it's serving the image from server A or B. But it is making a huge difference to *your browser* whether it needs to go out with a separate HTTP request to fetch the image or not. And Google is all about providing you as speedy an experience as possible, so you're going to use Google more.

Comment: This is where my infrastructure knowledge lets me down, I assume caching would occur on my pc, then at the company level, then the ISP, then others? If it was purely my browser to Google then I would agree with you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main goal of Google is to provide *you* with the fastest experience possible, so you're going to use Google more. They want to push all the data to you in the fastest way possible, so your browser doesn't have to go out with separate HTTP requests to fetch images. If the initial roundtrip time to get the HTML is, say, 200ms, requesting an image adds another 200ms or so to that, simply due to network roundtrip time. Each external resource adds such a roundtrip; even if they're parallelised to some degree, it will significantly add to the time until the page is "finished" loading.

Since you're likely only going to see images in search results very few times (they're not static, further searches you'll do will likely result in different images), there's no real need for any entity to cache that image for later reuse. Google has built the infrastructure that allows them to serve that image baked into the HTML page to you instantly, they don't care about HTTP/proxy caching all that much. Virtually all searches are happening over HTTPS anyway, making proxy caching impossible. Since search results are very diverse, there probably isn't a lot of regional caching across different users to be had in the first place.

TL;DR: the image is baked into the HTML to eliminate network roundtrip times to make the page load as instantly as possible.

Comment: I think the https comment is the real answer here as that stops any caching from any of the infrastructure between the browser and Google